# In what order are my gameobjects coming out of my list?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a list with gameobjects in it , and I have a bit of code that draws them to the screen

```
for (int i = Gameobject.gameobjects.Count -1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{           
   if (Gameobject.gameobjects[i] is GameItem ||
       Gameobject.gameobjects[i] is MenuItem ||
       Gameobject.gameobjects[i] is Rock ||
       Gameobject.gameobjects[i] is ChaseSprite||
       Gameobject.gameobjects[i] is MenuBar||
       Gameobject.gameobjects[i] is MenuBarItem)
   {      
    Gameobject.gameobjects[i].Draw(spriteBatch);                              
    #if Debug
    drawBorder(Gameobject.gameobjects[i].BoundingBox, 2, Color.Red);
    spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont,Rock.rockpieces.Count.ToString() , new Vector2(200, 200), Color.Pink);
    #endif

 }                                                        
}
```

---

The problem is that it doesn't seem to draw the objects in any particular order, in my case the menuItems are being drawn under the menubar making it so when the game runs the menuItems are not being shown.Now I know the menuItems are being drawn because I set the menubar to be 50% transparent when you put the mouse over it and when I mouse over you can clearly see the menuItems.This is a huge problem for me because of the way I have structured my game.

Comment: What order are you expecting them to be in?  Why dont you order the GameObject.gameobjects collection, or assemble it in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, the sort of collection you're using can influence the order of objects. If `gameobjects` is a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), they should be in the order you used `gameobjects.Add`.

The order of items you've specified in your list of `if..is..||` test only sepcifes the order they're tested in - it in no way sorts them, because you're only saying and if, not forcing one item to wait for another.

One way to solve this would be application of LINQ, either by multiple loops or by an OrderBy call.

UPDATE If you edit the collection during the course of a call, make sure to copy the result of the query into an Array or List via [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
foreach(var gameObj in Gameobject.gameobjects
    .OrderBy(SortGameObject)
    .ToArray())  // This will force iteration and cache the result, so changes to the orignal collection don't throw an exception
{
    gameObj.Draw(spriteBatch);                              
    #if Debug
    drawBorder(gameObj.BoundingBox, 2, Color.Red);
    spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont,Rock.rockpieces.Count.ToString() , new Vector2(200, 200), Color.Pink);
    #endif
}

private static int SortGameObject(Gameobject target)
{
   if (target is GameItem)        return 0;
   else if (target is MenuItem)   return 1;
   else if(target is Rock)        return 2;
   else if(target is ChaseSprit)  return 3;
   else if(target is MenuBar)     return 4;
   else if(target is MenuBarItem) return 5;
   else                           return int.MaxValue; // This forces any draws on unrecognized objects to go on top
                                                       // - to put unrecognized objects on the bottom, use -1 instead
}
```

This might be easier to solve by having all these inherit from a parent type which then has a DrawOrder parameter, which could reduce the query to

```
foreach(var gameObj in Gameobject.gameobjects.OrderBy(g => g.DrawOrder))
... // Draw calls as above
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a elementary Question but if SortGameObject method void how can you return 0 ? what are you returning it too.

Comment: Because I completely forgot to return int. I'll fix that in the answer n.n;

Comment: does it have to be a static

Comment: also do I have to use a foreach loop because I am using a forloop right now because I have to remove items from the list and foreach loops throw exceptions when you remove items from the list while the program is running.

Comment: The method is static just to make access easier - it's mostly an example. For loops are slightly safer for the exceptions that can be thrown due to removal - however, Linq offers some methods to help with that. I'll update my asnwer accordingly.